# we failed to identify your request PHPUNIT

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a test function -

```
class InstrumentTest extends TestCase {

    private $faker; 

    public function setUp() {
        $this->refreshApplication();
        $this->faker = Faker\Factory::create('en_EN');

        $user = App\User::find(2);

        $this->be($user);
    }

    /**
     * Test creating new instrument
     */
    public function testCreateNewInstrument() {
        $fakeName = $this->faker->name;

        $this->visit('/oem/instrument/create')
                ->type($fakeName, 'name')
                ->press('Create')
                ->seePageIs('/oem/instrument')
                ->see('Instrument Created Successfully!');

        # make sure that record is in the database
        $this->seeInDatabase('instrument', ['name' => $fakeName, 'company_id' => 1]);
    }
}
```

Each time I run "phpunit" my test die with following message in the console:
"We failed to identify your request."

I am not sure on how to fix this and if this is related to the middleware?

Answer (score 0):

Solution TestCase.php has a $baseUrl value that has to be your domain name